# no pg_hba.conf entry for host on timescaleDB hosted on aws cloud

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timescaledb

I have a timescale DB on aws and I am trying to create a connection to it with my nodejs script

This is my script

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
        const connectionString = 'postgres://host:port/defaultdb?sslmode=require'
        const pool = new Pool({
                  connectionString: connectionString,
        })
        pool.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
                  console.log(err, res)
                  pool.end()
        })
```

When I run this script I get this error no pg_hba.conf entry for host. How can I fix it?

Comment: on aws where you have your postgres db server is installed, edit the pg_hba.conf and add the ip of your client machine from where you are trying to connect with the db server.